# Magento extension not registering in core resources table

Tags: magento, resources

I am writing a Magento extension and I just cannot get it to show up in the core resources table. I believe I am declaring the resources part of my config correctly. Why is my extension not visible in the resource table?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <CTRL_Analytics>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </CTRL_Analytics>
    </modules>
    <global>
      <blocks>
        <analytics>
          <class>CTRL_Analytics_Block</class>
        </analytics>
      </blocks>
      
       <helpers>
          <analytics>
            <class>CTRL_Analytics_Helper</class>
          </analytics>
      </helpers>
        
      <resources>
        <analytics_setup>
            <setup>     
                <module>CTRL_Analytics</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </analytics_setup>
        
        <analytics_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </analytics_write>
        
        <analytics_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </analytics_read>
      </resources>
      
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
          <analytics translate="title" module="analytics">
              <title>Marketing and Analytics</title>
              <sort_order>100</sort_order>
              <action>analytics/admin</action>
          </analytics>
        </menu>
    </adminhtml>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <CTRL_Analytics>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>CTRL_Analytics</module>
                    <frontName>analytics</frontName>
                </args>
            </CTRL_Analytics>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your XML, you're naming your installer file

```
"mysql4-install-0.1.0.php",
```

but your starting module version is

```
"<version>0.2.0</version>"
```

Try changing your starting version to

```
"<version>0.1.0</version>"
```

or changing your installer file to

```
"mysql4-install-0.2.0.php".
```

Those file version numbers come from your module version number.

I always drop an exit or exception into any new installer file to make sure PHP is trying to load the file. Information is written out to the core_resource table only after a successful execution of this file, an exit or exception will prevent that writing.  This allows you to reload the page and have an installer run again and again until you get it right.

Comment: Nice catch Alan, I didn't read it carefully enough.  @user, I guess Alan answered your question about the sequence of writing to `core_resource`!

Comment: Thank you Alan and Jonathan! Both sets of advice contributed to the success of this script.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and took me a week (or made me lost a week!!!) to figure out why and it was dead simple.

Check the file and folder permissions. They're probably limited, change to read&write for both files and directories of your new extension, it'll work immediately. Does not have anything to do with the cache after all!!!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly (and I'm sure you've done this), clear and disable all cache.

Secondly, check that you able to access the Blocks and Helpers. If not, it might be a problem with your `app\etc\modules\CTRL_Analytics.xml`.  Does the module show up in the Admin under System>Config>Advanced?

Thirdly, do you have your `sql\analytics_setup\mysql4-install-0.1.0.php` and `sql\analytics_setup\mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.2.0.php` correctly named and coded.  I've found the mysql upgrade naming convention has tripped up a lot of people in the past.

Finally, try putting your server into debug and setting a breakpoint inside the `mysql4-install-0.1.0.php` to check whether the file is actually getting executed.  It might be attempting to run but silently failing on an SQL error (hate that!).

Hope one of these helps!
JD

Comment: I tried all of the above. I realize now that mysql4-install-0.1.0.php is not being executed.

Comment: Something like echo "here"; exit(); should work as a break point correct?

Comment: Shouldn't "analytics_setup" be written to the core_resources table when magento instantiates or does it depend on the successful execution of mysql4-install-0.1.0.php before it writes to core_resources?

Comment: does "echo 'hello'; exit()'" work as a breakpoint?  Effectively, yes, but in its most useful form, no.  Have a read of my answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329248/) to help setup your development environment so that you can debug using a toolset.  That will allow you to trace through the stack, examine the value of variables and generally get a HUGE improvement in your understanding of how Magento's codebase actually works.  You won't believe that you used to use "echo 'blah'; die();" once you get it working :) Good luck!

Comment: I'm not certain on when `core_resources` gets written, whether its before or after executing the install MySQL.  Based on what you're seeing, I'd guess that it's after!