# Custom Database Table not showing up in Magento

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, magento

I have created a custom module with a custom database table in it to store/fetch values. I have followed the follwing directory structure, but still my table doesn't show up in the database. Any Ideas as to why

```
app/code/local
Namespace
 Module
   Block

   controllers
     IndexController.php

   etc
     config.xml

   Helper
     Data.php

   Model
     Module.php
     Observer.php
     Mysql4
       Module.php
       Module
         Collection.php

   sql
     module_setup
        mysql4-install-0.1.0.php

   app/etc
      Namespace_Module.xml
```

This is my config.xml

```
<config>    
<modules>
    <Namespace_Module>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Namespace_Module>
</modules>
<global>
<helpers>
    <module>
        <class>Namespace_Module_Helper</class>
    </module>
</helpers>  
<models>
    <module>
        <class>Namespace_Module_Model</class>
    <resourceModel>module_mysql4</resourceModel>
    </module>
    <module_mysql4>
        <class>Namespace_Module_Model_Mysql4</class>
        <entities>
            <module>
                <table>module</table>
            </module>
        </entities>
    </module_mysql4>
 </models>
<resources>
        <module_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Namespace_Module</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </module_setup>
        <module_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </module_write>
        <module_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </module_read>
    </resources>
    <blocks>
        <module>
            <class>Namespace_Module_Block</class>
        </module>
    </blocks>
 </global>
 <crontab>
<jobs>
<send_reviews_email>
    <schedule><cron_expr>*/5 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
    <run><model>module/observer::sendReviewsEmail</model></run>
</send_reviews_email>
</jobs>
 </crontab>
 <frontend>
   <routers>
     <module>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
            <module>Namespace_Module</module>
            <frontName>module</frontName>
        </args>
      </module>
    </routers>
  </frontend>       
</config>
```

This is my mysql4-install-0.1.0.php

```
<?php
  $installer = $this;
  $installer->startSetup();
  $installer->run("
  -- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('cronemails')};
  CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('cronemails')} (
  `cronemails_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `order_id` varchar(255) default '',
  `order_email_id` varchar(255) default '',
  `review_request` smallint(6) NOT NULL default '0',
  `coupon_sent` smallint(6) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`cronemails_id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    ");
  $installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: have you configured the setup in your config.xml?

Comment: Yes I have. But It isn't showing in the core_resources table.

Comment: do you care paste it here so we can check if there is no error

Comment: and also paste the mysql4-install-0.1.0.php's content

Comment: I have edited my question to accomodate config.xml n mysql4-install-0.1.0.php..Please have a look and see if you can help me o spot any mistake.

Comment: does your PHP log file say anything *else* about your module, missing data helper file, missing anything, syntax error ?

Comment: Did you create a module registration file under `app/etc/modules/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing the version number to 0.1.1 and rename your file to `mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1.php.
though as you had 1.6.1.0 I'm not sure if this will work: in case it doesn't, try 1.6.1.0-1.6.1.1

Comment: Sry to have left the conversation midway, due to lost internet connectivity. I wanted to ask you if the sql/module_Setup folder will only contain one file ie. mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1.php or .02.php ?

Comment: Hi, just wanted to let you know, that your solution worked!! :) I changed the config.xml to 0.0.2 and renamed the file to mysql4-upgrade-0.0.1-0.02.php. IT worked. I can now see my module in core_resource table. So does this mean I can now save and fetch data to this table using Magento methods.
Thanks again @Dick  Laurent. U guys were of great help! Really appreciate it.

Comment: Since I dont actually see a table but just the entry of my module in core_resource table, Can I o not use the methods to set and get data from my custom table?

Comment: @ivn no, to save/fetch data to/from this table you have to create the proper classes. I recomend you to study a bit, there is a lot of information out there. You could even start with the module creator. Please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: I have accepted your answer. Could you provide me any links to read on more. I have already followed the steps described in this link http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table but to no luck. So if you have any other links or blogposts/tutorials in mind then please do fwd me the link. Till then thanks a lot for your help again!

Comment: @ivn it has been a long time since I started studying Magento, so I don't have the links anymore. But magentocommerce's wiki is definitely a good place to start. Checkout also all you can from Alan Storm. There are a few post here on SO too. It ain't easy at first, but I can tell you that it's not impossible either. Be pacient and persevere. good luck.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if your module is already in core_resource table. If yes, then delete it from there and try again.
2. Check that your module version in config.xml equal or greater then 0.1.0

Comment: Its not in my core_resource table. And I changed my module version from 0.1.0 to 1.6.1.0.. Still it doesn't show up

Comment: what is your module version right now and what version is in mysql4-install-X.X.X.php ?

Comment: My module version is 1.6.1.0 n mysql4-install-0.1.0.php. Should I change it to mysql4-install-1.6.1.php?

Comment: i'd rather suggest changing both to 0.1.0

Comment: well then thats wat it was bfre...config.xml was 0.1.0 n so was the mysql4 file...stil d table dint show up

Comment: In this case please take a look at a splendid debugging tutorial of module installation script written by Alan Storm http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717535/my-magento-extension-install-script-will-not-run

Comment: if it was like that before then it definitely have to be in core_resource table look for youModuleName_setup entry.

Comment: I have double refreshed, cleared d cache n checked it multiple times. But cant find mymodule_setup record entry in core_resource table.

Comment: Tried your debugging code in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php in *protected function _modifyResourceDb($actionType, $fromVersion, $toVersion)* . Still dint find anything. Can you again point out which page needs to be loaded in order to find the debugging info. Just in case If I'm searching in the wrong place.

Comment: any page. the install script works as follows. it gets the list of all magento modules. verifies with core_resourse table which modules have not installed updates and run those files. this happens on any page load. have you added Alan's debug code to your app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php ? Did you got an exception?

Comment: Thats what the thing is. I am not getting any exception. I have written the code exactly as mentioned in that post, but still fail to get any exception :(

Comment: are you sure your files are saved to the server? maybe you are restricted by file permissions but still seeing file from your FTP client cache?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6013/discussion-between-ivn-and-dick-laurent)