# Magento Install script never runs

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I am trying to create a custom table using custom module. I have been following [Alan Storm's article](http://alanstorm.com/magento_setup_resources) to create a custom table

This is my folder structure

```
CM
 Tablecreation
 etc >> config.xml (has 1.6.0.0 as the version mentioned)
 Helper >> Data.php
 controllers >> IndexController.php
 Model
  Actualtable.php
  Mysql4
   Actualtable.php
  Resource
   Mysql4
     Setup.php
  sql
   tablecreation_setup
     install-1.6.0.0.php
```

This is my config.xml file.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <config>
  <modules>
    <CM_Tablecreation>
        <version>1.6.0.0</version>
    </CM_Tablecreation>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <tablecreation>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>CM_Tablecreation</module>
                <frontName>tablecreation</frontName>
            </args>
        </tablecreation>
    </routers>
</frontend>    
<global>

    <models>
        <tablecreation>
            <class>CM_Tablecreation_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>tablecreation_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </tablecreation>
        <tablecreation_mysql4>
        <class>CM_Tablecreation_Model_Mysql4</class>     
        <entities>
            <actualtable>
                <table>actual_table</table>
            </actualtable>
        </entities>                    
    </tablecreation_mysql4>
    </models>

    <resources>
    <tablecreation_setup>
    <setup>
        <module>CM_Tablecreation</module>
        <class>CM_Tablecreation_Model_Resource_Mysql4_Setup</class>
    </setup>
    <connection>
        <use>core_setup</use>
    </connection>
    </tablecreation_setup>
    <tablecreation_write>
        <connection>
            <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
    </tablecreation_write>
    <tablecreation_read>
        <connection>
            <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
    </tablecreation_read>      
</resources>      

    <helpers>
            <tablecreation>
                <class>CM_Tablecreation_Helper</class>
            </tablecreation>
    </helpers>
</global>
</config>
```

And this is the error I get every time

```
  a:5:{i:0;s:69:"/home/dev/public_html/app/code///sql/tablecreation_setup not found";i:1;s:818:"#0 /home/dev/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(421): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('install', '', '1.6.0.0')
```

I tried debugging by putting try catch with exception messages in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Resource/Setup.php as suggested in some of the previous similar questions on this topic, but to no success

My module isn't even getting listed in core_resource table. And even if some how it does, the table surely never gets created.

I have also had the situation when it did list in core_resource table but If I delete my module's record from the table (to run install script again) and then try to refresh any page of my site I again end up getting error page opening the report of which I find the same error.

Basically any article over the net I follow, I get stuck at this same error. Please help me explain this error and what's causing it. Probably also if some one can suggest what's the solution to sort it.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see a couple of issues with what you've posted:

1. Your install script needs to be called mysql4-install-1.6.0.0.php.  If Magento can't find the setup script because it's named incorrectly, it won't be able to run it, so I'd rename your install-1.6.0.0.php to mysql4-install-1.6.0.0.php.
2. You'll need a resources tag in the global section in your config.xml file which looks like this:

   ```
   <resources>
       <tablecreation_setup>
           <setup>
               <module>CM_Tablecreation</module>
           </setup>
           <connection>
               <use>core_setup</use>
           </connection>
       </tablecreation_setup>
   </resources>
   ```
3. Check your app/etc/modules.CM_Tablecreation.xml file.  The error message you've posted is interesting in that the code pool and module name is missing from the path where it's attempting tom locate the setup file.  Check that your xml file has a config > modules > YourModule_NameHere > codePool tag (note codePool with a capital P) which contains the string "core", "community" or "local" depending on the location in which your module resides.

You may find some assistance in [my previous answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8750895/38458), and [Alan Storm's definitive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4766837/38458) on the subject.

PS: Your extension version doesn't need to be the same version number as Magento itself.  Just start with whatever version number makes you happy and increment as required.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had it named as mysql4-install-0.0.1 but then since even that wasn't helping I tried 1.6.0.0. But anyway I have renamed it back to mysql4-install-1.6.0.0.php and my `<resources>` tag was more or less same except for the `<class></class>` thing which I have removed. I can now see my module listed in core_resource table but still can't see any actual table. This is what has happened previously too. And I have tried Alan Storm's debugging techniques but it doesn't throw me any error/exception. So how do I get the actual table in place?

Comment: Ok I just again tried Alan Storm's debugging techniques. I deleted my module entry from `core_resource` table, modified my core Setup.php to throw those exceptions and tried reloading the page again and got an error report. Opening which I again found the same error as I have mentioned in the question. So I have no clue why its throwing an error now. However If I insert the record back, I get no error but again, no table as well.

Comment: The record in core_resource indicates that the setup script has run successfully.  While it's there Magento will not attempt to run your setup script again because it believes it has already successfully done so.

Comment: Well if it has run successfully, why isn't my table not created? And if i try to run the script again by deleting the record from the table, I get an error page again which doesn't go until I put the record back and once I do that, I am not able to run my upgrade script. This whole problem is driving me nuts for quite some days now. Please suggest me what is it that I do wrong every time wrt every article on the net.