# Magento Installer Script is not running

Tags: php, magento

I am learning Magento. In this regard I am following this (http://www.opensourceforwebtechnologies.com/create-custom-model-in-magento/) tutorial.

My config.xml file is like below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Helloworld>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Easylife_Helloworld>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <helloworld>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Easylife_Helloworld</module>
                    <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
                </args>
            </helloworld>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <helloworld>
                    <file>helloworld.xml</file>
                </helloworld>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <helloworld>
                <class>Easylife_Helloworld_Block</class>
            </helloworld>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <helloworld>
                <class>Easylife_Helloworld_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>helloworld_resource</resourceModel>
            </helloworld>
            <helloworld_resource>
                <class>Easylife_Helloworld_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <helloworld>
                        <table>helloworld</table>
                    </helloworld>
                </entities>
            </helloworld_resource>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <helloworld_setup>
                <setup>
                    <class>Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </helloworld_setup>
            <helloworld_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </helloworld_read>
            <helloworld_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </helloworld_write>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

I read this ([Create a new table from magento module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749596/create-a-new-table-from-magento-module?lq=1)) question also.

There is not entry in `core_resource` table in the database.

Location of my script as like below image.

[image]

Here is the screenshot of my `core_resource` table.

[image]

Could any one help me to run my installer script ?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it is not showing in core resource table then it means you have not created module's xml file.

1. Go to this location app/etc/modules/
2. Create a xml file with name {{name_spac}}_{{module_name}}.xml in your example Easylife_Helloworld.xml. Open this file and write this:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config>
       <modules>
            <Fontis_FeedsGenerator>
                <active>true</active>
                <codePool>local</codePool> /*This is your module location in app/code/ */
            </Fontis_FeedsGenerator>
      </modules>
   </config>
   ```
3. And do remember to refresh cache System >> Cache Management

Also Go to System > Configuration > Advanced > Advanced and see if your module appears in the "Disable Module Output" list or not.