# Where are SQL updates run?

Tags: magento

I have several updates.

My module release is 0.3.0.

Sql updates:

- `mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.2.0.php`
- `mysql4-upgrade-0.2.0-0.3.0.php`

The first update works perfect.
The second one doesn't work. Magento doesn't include it.

So where does the sql update logic store? I would like to debug it somehow.

Comment: Did you updated your module version in config.xml file?

Comment: Debugging tips here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4766837/4668

Comment: @Alan Storm thanks for the link!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at

1. Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyUpdates() and
2. Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyDataUpdates().

This may be enough to get you started. Tell me if you need more advice.

Answer (score 2):

The table your interested in is the `core_resource`.  If you need to rerun a migration you can edit the `version` or `data_version` column of the record, changing the version of your schema that Magento thinks is installed, and refresh your browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()` and `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllDataUpdates()` methods.