# Setup resource not working in Magento 1.6.0

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to build a module for Magento 1.6.0. Here is my config. I don't know what is wrong with it. The setup sql script is not running.

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <MagePsycho_Shipmentfiles>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </MagePsycho_Shipmentfiles>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
           <shipmentfiles>
                <class>MagePsycho_Shipmentfiles_Model</class>
            </shipmentfiles>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <shipmentfiles>
                <class>MagePsycho_Shipmentfiles_Helper</class>
            </shipmentfiles>
        </helpers>
        <resources>
            <shipmentfiles_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>MagePsycho_Shipmentfiles</module>
                </setup>
            </shipmentfiles_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
    .......
    ..........
```

I have created install-1.0.0.php file inside sql/shipmentfiles_setup directory. But this file doesn't seem to load. Also, I have checked in core_resource table. It doesn't have any record of "shipmentfiles_setup".

Comment: have you cleared your tmp and cache directories since adding that?

Comment: Thanks Shad, it was due to tmp and cache files I guess... after clearing them worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

per my comment, Magento caches a lot of it's settings. After installing something/changing configuration it's a good idea to clear out the `/tmp` and `/cache` directories.

Answer (score 2):

Your file have to be named `mysql4-install-1.0.0.php`, not `install-1.0.0.php`.

If even then your setup will not run then use the most comprehensive guide on this subject ever written [My Magento Extension Install Script Will Not Run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717535/my-magento-extension-install-script-will-not-run) by Alan Storm.

Comment: Laurent, I am trying to make module for version above 1.6. install-1.0.0.php should work. Infact, Varien is going to deprecate mysql4-install-1.0.0.php convension.