# Creating two new database tables for Magento

Tags: database, magento

I'm trying to add two tables to magento but it still dosen't work! I don't get the tables in MySQL. 
There's no error message, just nothing happens.
I can't find where the mistake is;
I already checked all my pages.

This is my XML code in config.xml:

```
    <models>
        <interactivebanner>
            <class>Kiwi_InteractiveBanner_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>InteractiveBanner_resource</resourceModel>
        </interactivebanner>
        <interactivebanner_resource>
            <class>Kiwi_InteractiveBanner_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <interactivebanner>
                    <table>interactivebanner</table>
                </interactivebanner>
                <interactivebanner2>
                    <table>interactivebanner_prod</table>
                </interactivebanner2>
            </entities>
        </interactivebanner_resource>
    </models>
```

and this is the setup page  :

```
<?php 

$installer = $this;
  $installer->startSetup();

  $installer->run("
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `{$this->getTable('interactivebanner/interactivebanner')}`;
create table `{$this->getTable('interactivebanner/interactivebanner')}`
(
   ENTITY_ID            int not null,
   NAME                 varchar(100),
   LINK                 varchar(100),
   STATUS               int,
   primary key (ENTITY_ID)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `{$this->getTable('interactivebanner/interactivebanner_prod')}`;
create table `{$this->getTable('interactivebanner/interactivebanner_prod')}`
(
   PROD_ID              int not null,
   ENTITY_ID            int,
   POSI_V               float,
   POSI_H               float,
   primary key (PROD_ID)
);

alter table banner_pro add constraint FK_RELATION_1 foreign key (ENTITY_ID)
      references banner (ENTITY_ID) on delete restrict on update restrict;

");

  $installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: Please define "doesn't work" more precisely. What do you expect and what does actually happen. Do you get error messages? If so, post them.

Comment: sorry , i don't get the tables in MySql !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a mistake on my config.xml ! 
an uppercase missing :) 
sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Is this existing module you want to upgrade?

If so, you will have to bump the module version before your upgrade script runs. If it's a separate module you have to make the mysql4-setup-<version>.php with a version so high or above that will create the tables. Also you will require to have module declaration in your app/etc/Myself_Interactivebanner.xml so that Magento knew about the module existence.

To get more certain answer provide more details about the environment you have.

Comment: this is my own module, i've put the version number on the config file , like this  <version>1.0.0.0.2</version>  
And my Upgrade file name is : upgrade-1.0.0.0.1-1.0.0.0.2.php

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, your install script is not running. This can happen for multiple reasons. I would look at this post that helped me get my install script running:

[My Magento Extension Install Script Will Not Run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717535/my-magento-extension-install-script-will-not-run)