# Magento Doesn't Run Sql Setup Script

Tags: php, magento

Magento doesn't run installer script of my module.But setup script version is getting added in `core_resource` table.Here are my files

Part of config.xml

```
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Company_Brands>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            </Company_Brands>
        </modules>
        <global>
            <models>
                <brands>
                    <class>Company_Brands_Model</class>
                    <resourceModel>brands_mysql4</resourceModel>
                </brands>
                <brands_mysql4>
                    <class>Company_Brands_Model_Mysql4</class>              
                </brands_mysql4>
            </models>

        <resources>
            <brands_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Company_Brands</module>
                    <class>Company_Brands_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </brands_setup>
            <brands_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </brands_read>
            <brands_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </brands_write>
        </resources>
</global>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Company/Brands/sql/brands_setup/mysql4-install-1.0.0.php

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$data = array(
    'label' => 'Brands',
    'type' => 'select'
    'input' => 'text',
    'global'=> Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'required'=>false,
    'is_configurable'=>true,
    'compareble'=>true,
    'filterable' =>true,
    'searchable'=>true
);

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product','some_brands',$data);

$installer->endSetup();
```

app/code/local/Company/Brands/Model/Mysql4/Setup.php

```
class Company_Brands_Model_Mysql4_Setup extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup
{

}
```

Comment: Do you have developer mode turned on? Are you receiving any other errors?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717535/my-magento-extension-install-script-will-not-run and many others

Comment: Why do you need blank Setup model?

Comment: @Tim He didn't. If you don't make changes to the setup model, one can use the `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup` directly.

Comment: @blakcaps what is your code for setup.php file ? plz can you tell me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's suggestions.

`,` was missing after `'select'`

```
$data = array(
    'label' => 'Brands',
    'type' => 'select'
    'input' => 'text',
```

It should be

```
$data = array(
        'label' => 'Brands',
        'type' => 'select',
        'input' => 'text',
```