# After using my new magento module: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table XXX does

Tags: magento

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'desbest_full2.showdown_matches' doesn't exist

But why, if I've got a mysql setup script inside `app/code/local/Desbest/Showdown/sql/Showdown_setup/mysql4-install-1.php`

```
<?php
echo 'Running This Upgrade: '.get_class($this)."\n <br /> \n"; die("Exit for now");

$installer = $this;
/* @var $installer Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup */
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("

    CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('showdown_matches')} (
    --CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `showdown_matches` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `firstproductid` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `secondproductid` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `datenumber` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `showdown_votes` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `matchid` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `votedfor` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
      `ip` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `datenumber` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;



");
$installer->endSetup();
```

The module worked on my original Magento installation.

Comment: hi desbest, what is your config.xml looks like?

Comment: Here it is. https://gist.github.com/8a2da27d4f71834292f6

Comment: Is the commented line worked? --CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `showdown_matches`. Did you ever get that error message, then you fixed it, after that you refresh the page (and the error still persist?). If it was like that, look at your url, if you're accessing 'local.com/errors/report.php?id=....' -> that is the problem. That is a static page. I found nothings wrong with your code (if I didn't miss anything).

Comment: I used the commented line, and it didn't help. There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with my code from my end either. Weird.

Comment: does your code ever reach the  die("Exit for now"); statement in your install script?

Comment: The reason the setup script is not running is because it doesn't suppose to run. See mjohnsonperl answer, check the core_resource table where Magento keeps track of the installed modules and versions. `SELECT * 
FROM  `core_resource` 
WHERE  `code` LIKE  '%showdown%'`

Answer (score 5):

It is possible that your setup script is not running because Magento thinks it has already been run. You can check the database table core_resource for a record for your module with the modules version. This resource record is how Magento knows if it has already run a modules setup scripts, or determines if it needs to run an upgrade script from an older version to a newer one.

If you delete the record for your module from the core_resource table Magento will attempt to execute your setup script the next time Magento generates a page.

I would also expect that you'd need to remove the `die("Exit for now");` from the setup script so that it actually reaches the part where it creates the tables. If the setup script launches and calls the die() function and ends the execution of that script, I think it might go ahead and create the core_resource record indicating it's completed the setup script and won't run it again unless you remove that record from the core_resource table.

You can find some information about setup scripts in the Magento Knowledge Base:
[Magento for Developers: Part 6 - Magento Setup Resources](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-6-magento-setup-resources/)

You might also check the module config XML file to make sure the version there matches the version of the setup script's file name.

```
<modules>
    <Desbest_Showdown>
        <version>1</version>
    </Desbest_Showdown>
</modules>
<global>
    <resources>
        <showdown_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Desbest_Showdown</module>
            </setup>
        </showdown_setup>
    </resources>
</global>
```

Another thing I thought of is file/directory name case sensitivity. If you setup a bunch of stuff on a Mac where you have a case insensitive file system everything works fine, and then move files to a linux box where the file system is case sensitive you'll have issues with files not getting found. You listed your filename as `app/code/local/Desbest/Showdown/sql/Showdown_setup/mysql4-install-1.php` and I think the directory `Showdown_setup` may need to be all lowercase `showdown_setup`.

Comment: I agree with the case sensitive thing. It is a good practice to pay attention with case sensitive issue.

Comment: **1.** There is no database row of showdown inside `core_resource`. **2.** It is supposed to have `die()` as I am making plugins so it's there for testing. From personal experience, no, it doesn't make the `core_resource` database row. **3.** I've renamed `sql/Showdown_setup` to `sql/showdown_setup`, and it had no effect. **4.** The version number inside `config.xml` and the `mysql4-install-1.php` file matches.

Comment: I've figured out what the problem is now. It was the case of the folders. I changed `Showdown_setup` to `showdown_setup` and now it works!

Answer (score 1):

There's steps in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717535/my-magento-extension-install-script-will-not-run/4766837) for debugging non-running setup resource scripts.