# Magento: why resource script doesn't install?

Tags: magento, resources, attributes

I took an example from [here](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-add-new-custom-category-attribute-in-magento/).

My folder structure is:

```
- Avq
-  -  Import
-  -    -    ...
-  -    -    etc
-  -    -     -  config.xml
-  -    -    sql
-  -    -     -  avq_import_setup
-  -    -     -       -            mysql4-install-0.1.0.php
```

My config.xml is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Avq_Import>
                <version>1.0.0.1</version>
            </Avq_Import>
        </modules>

        <global>
            <resources>
                <avq_import_setup>
                    <setup>
                        <module>Avq_Import</module>
                        <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                    </setup>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_setup</use>
                    </connection>
                </avq_import_setup>
                <avq_import_write>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_write</use>
                    </connection>
                </avq_import_write>
                <avq_import_read>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_read</use>
                    </connection>
                </avq_import_read>
            </resources>
        </global>
    </config>
```

and mysql4-install-0.1.0.php code inside:

```
<?php
die("!");
$installer = $this;
//....
```

And I cannot even get "!".
Where is error could be here?
Is there any methods to debug xml config?

PS: I turned off cache, tured on my module and **avq_import_setup** is absent in the core_resource table.

Comment: Tips for debugging a setup resource script: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4766837/4668

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need 2 things to magento execute your setup, first inside one folder with the same name of the node in your case is avq_import_setup, so its be avq_import_setup/mysql4-install-x.x.x.php, look i put x.x.x on the file name, you must change it by the version of your module, in your case its 1.0.0.1, and your file is 0.1.0, its the second thing.

And to finish, this execute just 1 time, when magento record on database your module info its done no more then 1 time.

So, if you try install your module and dont run the setup file, probably the magento already register your module on db, and dont run anymore your setup. In this case you must go to 'core_resource' table, and find your module and remove it. Now you can try install again.

Comment: I've changed file version to 1.0.0.1. Nothing changed. Also core_resource table haven't my record yet.

Comment: Try put its on module/sql/avq_import_setup/mysql4-install-1.0.0.1.php.

Comment: This is the right steps to do it, if dont work its something else wrong. Your module is active?? Try install your module on other store to test, first time.

Comment: yup, that is the way it is. my module is active, catalog structure and file name are correct

Comment: sometimes magento lose himself on this case. so try install on other store to see if works.

Comment: Installed new strore - nothing new =(

Comment: you are cleaning the cache before try install??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15683/discussion-between-anthony-and-guerra)