# Magento: working XML but install script not running

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-6-magento-setup-resources

This is the link from where I am trying to create resource setup. I followed exactly. Everything works perfect except that the installer script is not getting run i.e. when opening any Magento page it is not dying since it is written die statement in installer script.

Answer (score 2):

Start by looking in the `core_resource` table.  Do you see your resource's name? That means Magento thinks it already installed the resource.  Delete this row, clear your cache, and try again.

Also, [some debugging statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717535/my-magento-extension-install-script-will-not-run) that take a look at the `$files` variable in

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
protected function _modifyResourceDb($actionType, $fromVersion, $toVersion)
{
    ...
}
```

should tell you what files Magento thinks it should load.