# Magento - create new customer attribute

Tags: magento, module, attributes

I need to create 4 new customer attributes in my magento store. I have created a module as below to do so:

```
Customerattribute >
    etc > config.xml
    Model > Mysql4 > Setup.php
    sql > customerattribute_setup > mysql4-install-0.0.1.php
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Custom_Customerattribute>
      <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Custom_Customerattribute>
  </modules>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <customerattribute_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Custom_Customerattribute</module>
                    <class>Custom_Customerattribute_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                ....
            </customerattribute_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

Setup.php

```
class Custom_Customerattribute_Model_Mysql4_Setup extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup 
{
    /**
     * This method returns true if the attribute exists.
     * 
     * @param string|int $entityTypeId
     * @param string|int $attributeId
     * @return bool
     */
    public function attributeExists($entityTypeId, $attributeId) 
    {
        try 
        {
            $entityTypeId = $this->getEntityTypeId($entityTypeId);
            $attributeId = $this->getAttributeId($entityTypeId, $attributeId);
            return !empty($attributeId);
        } 
        catch(Exception $e) 
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

mysql4-install-0.0.1.php

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$entity = $installer->getEntityTypeId('customer');

if(!$installer->attributeExists($entity, 'paypal')) {
    $installer->removeAttribute($entity, 'paypal');
}

$installer->addAttribute($entity, 'paypal', array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'label' => 'Paypal',
        'input' => 'text',
        'visible' => TRUE,
        'required' => FALSE,
        'default_value' => '',
        'adminhtml_only' => '0'
));

$forms = array(
    'adminhtml_customer',
    'customer_account_edit'
);
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute($installer->getEntityTypeId('customer'), 'paypal');
$attribute->setData('used_in_forms', $forms);
$attribute->save();

$installer->endSetup();
```

This works for my first customer attribute of `paypal` but i now want to be able to add 3 others. I had hoped that if i change the `mysql4-install-0.0.1.php` file to say this:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$entity = $installer->getEntityTypeId('customer');

if(!$installer->attributeExists($entity, 'attribute_2')) {
    $installer->removeAttribute($entity, 'attribute_2');
}

$installer->addAttribute($entity, 'attribute_2', array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'label' => 'Attribute 2',
        'input' => 'text',
        'visible' => TRUE,
        'required' => FALSE,
        'default_value' => '',
        'adminhtml_only' => '0'
));

$forms = array(
    'adminhtml_customer',
    'customer_account_edit'
);
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute($installer->getEntityTypeId('customer'), 'attribute_2');
$attribute->setData('used_in_forms', $forms);
$attribute->save();

$installer->endSetup();
```

and uploaded the new file and went back onto the site `attribute_2` would be added but it isn't.

Why does this work once but not again?

Comment: Did you manage? And could you share the extension/code if possible (we need 4 attributes too) ;P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to add new file(installer script) and the file name should be,

```
 mysql4-upgrade-0.0.2-0.0.1.php
```

So now in this you can add your installer script like,

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$entity = $installer->getEntityTypeId('customer');

if(!$installer->attributeExists($entity, 'attribute_2')) {
    $installer->removeAttribute($entity, 'attribute_2');
}

$installer->addAttribute($entity, 'attribute_2', array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'label' => 'Attribute 2',
        'input' => 'text',
        'visible' => TRUE,
        'required' => FALSE,
        'default_value' => '',
        'adminhtml_only' => '0'
));

$forms = array(
    'adminhtml_customer',
    'customer_account_edit'
);
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute($installer->getEntityTypeId('customer'), 'attribute_2');
$attribute->setData('used_in_forms', $forms);
$attribute->save();

$installer->endSetup();
```

And you need to update the config.xml file also. So it should be,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Custom_Customerattribute>
      <version>0.0.2</version>
    </Custom_Customerattribute>
  </modules>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <customerattribute_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Custom_Customerattribute</module>
                    <class>Custom_Customerattribute_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                ....
            </customerattribute_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

For more information, go **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717535/my-magento-extension-install-script-will-not-run)**. If you have any doubt please comment here.

**Update:**
I'm sorry. The file name should be like this,

```
   mysql4-upgrade-0.0.2-0.0.1.php
```

The `core_resource` table contains module entries. Now the `0.0.2` is also updated. So magento will not look up your module(updated) xml files to load. so you need to again change the file name to  `mysql4-upgrade-0.0.3-0.0.2.php` or delete that entry in your database and rename your module version to fresh like  `mysql4-upgrade-0.0.0.php`

**Update-2:**

Here I have attached new codes, I checked in my local its working fine,

app/code/local/Packagename/Modulename/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Packagename_Modulename>
      <version>0.0.0</version>
    </Packagename_Modulename>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <modulename>
        <class>Packagename_Modulename_Helper</class>
      </modulename>
    </helpers>
    <models>
      <modulename>
        <class>Packagename_Modulename_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>modulename_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </modulename>
    </models>
    <resources>
      <customerattribute1415104755_setup>
        <setup>
          <module>Packagename_Modulename</module>
          <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
        </setup>
        <connection>
          <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
      </customerattribute1415104755_setup>
      <customerattribute1415104755_write>
        <connection>
          <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
      </customerattribute1415104755_write>
      <customerattribute1415104755_read>
        <connection>
          <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
      </customerattribute1415104755_read>
    </resources>
  </global>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Packagename/Modulename/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php
class Packagename_Modulename_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

app/code/local/Packagename/Modulename/sql/customerattribute1415104755_setup/mysql4-install-0.0.0.php

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();


$installer->addAttribute("customer", "myattrbute1",  array(
    "type"     => "varchar",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "My attribute-1",
    "input"    => "text",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => ""

    ));

        $attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "myattrbute1");


$used_in_forms=array();

$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
$used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
        $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_system", 0)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 1)
        ->setData("sort_order", 100)
        ;
        $attribute->save();




$installer->addAttribute("customer", "myattrbute2",  array(
    "type"     => "varchar",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "My attribute-2",
    "input"    => "text",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => ""

    ));

        $attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "myattrbute2");


$used_in_forms=array();

$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
$used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
        $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_system", 0)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 1)
        ->setData("sort_order", 100)
        ;
        $attribute->save();




$installer->addAttribute("customer", "myattrbute3",  array(
    "type"     => "varchar",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "My attribute-3",
    "input"    => "text",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => ""

    ));

        $attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "myattrbute3");


$used_in_forms=array();

$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
$used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
        $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_system", 0)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 1)
        ->setData("sort_order", 100)
        ;
        $attribute->save();




$installer->addAttribute("customer", "myattrbute4",  array(
    "type"     => "varchar",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "My attribute-4",
    "input"    => "text",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => ""

    ));

        $attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "myattrbute4");


$used_in_forms=array();

$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
$used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
        $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_system", 0)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 1)
        ->setData("sort_order", 100)
        ;
        $attribute->save();



$installer->endSetup();
```

And finally enable your module in,
app/etc/modules/Packagename_Modulename.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Packagename_Modulename>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.0.0</version>
    </Packagename_Modulename>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: Thanks but this still doesn't work. I've refreshed all cache's before and after, cleared the cache and cache storage. Also called the setup file as you said - `mysql4-install-0.0.1-0.0.2.php` and also `mysql4-install-0.0.2.php` with no luck

Comment: I'm sorry. File name should be like this mysql4-install-0.0.2-0.0.1.php. I have update my answer, please check it.

Comment: Updated the filename but that still didn't work. I looked in `core_resource` database table and could see the updated 0.0.2 version for that module.  Looking elsewhere online it looked like deleting that and then running again would solve and it did, not sure why?!

Comment: I have updated my answer. please checkout and let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: Your code also works, thanks for the in depth answer

Answer (score 0):

I think theres an error in the code presented earlier:

```
if(!$installer->attributeExists($entity, 'attribute_2')) {
    $installer->removeAttribute($entity, 'attribute_2');
}
```

... seems to be saying 'if the new attribute doesn't exist - delete it'

You probably want this:

```
if ($installer->attributeExists($entity, 'attribute_2')) {
    $installer->removeAttribute($entity, 'attribute_2');
}
```