# How does Magento Install,Update scripts Actually work?

Tags: php, magento, plugins, magento-1.9

I researched a lot for 5 hours.

I actually referred the code given **[here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/65751/add-new-field-in-magento1-9-customer-registration)** to add new attribute to magento database for **Customer**.

For that I initially used `install-1.0.0` script. But i needed some other fields to add to database so I created update script `upgrade-1.0.0-1.0.1` and added `<version>1.0.1</version>` to my own extension "  `StackExchange_Customer/etc/StackExchange_Customer.xml`

But still the fields are not getting added in DB.

There is no clear guide regarding

1. How `Install script works` ,  `Update script works`??
2. Which call goes into which file ??
3. When actually Update, Install module get called ?
4. Does it get called when I enable/disable module ? Or anything else ?

   Magento is already complex, without proper documentation on net ,
   stackoverflow , it has become even more complicated.

Thanks.

Comment: Hoping to come back round and answer this all, but for starters, have you checked the `core_resource` table in your DB? This should list the "version" and tell you whether Magento has seen your update

Comment: No there is no record of my module and not of my module version. But surprisingly it added 1 record i wanted from my script module . How ?

Comment: If there's no record in core_resource, most probably an error occurred in the install script. It added the 1 customer and then an error occured, preventing the setup from completing.

Comment: But that answer was given by http://magento.stackexchange.com/users/146/marius , so you dont think he will give wrong code .

Comment: In the install script for app/code/local/StackExchange/Customer/sql/stackexchange_customer_setup/install-1.0.0.php, $this->startSetup() and $this->endSetup() are needed.

Comment: A i already did still wont work

Answer (score 1):

Here is the best article for this by alanstorm: 
http://alanstorm.com/magento_setup_resources

Also explained here as well: [My Magento Extension Install Script Will Not Run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717535/my-magento-extension-install-script-will-not-run)