# Magento - Autocomplete Suggest Search Not Working

Tags: search, magento, autocomplete, magento-1.4, autosuggest

I have incorporated a new theme in Magento v1.4.2.0, and have completed all the necessary changes, but only following true Magento way of overriding the Magento modules & methods.

My only problem is that the auto complete suggest search functionality in the front-end is not working at all. The AJAX is running as I can view the calls in "`Firebug`" (with the status showing as "200 OK"), but the search result dropdown isn’t coming.

Some more info:

- Checked the method of the form and it is set as "`get`".
- Name of the text field in the "`form.mini.phtml`" is "`q`".
- Checked both the Log Files (`exception.log` & `system.log`), but nothing is printed here regarding auto complete search.
- Checked the settings of Minimal Query Length (from "**System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog Search > Minimal Query Length**") and it is set to "`1`".
- Incorporated all the HTML in the "`form.mini.phtml`" page as precisely as possible, along with including all the required JS files without any errors in them. As a result, the `Firebug` is reporting the `blank` / `NULL` AJAX responses, without any errors.

---

**Edit:-**
I am also getting another problem. Say I have 4 products, each starting with a name "**Test**". Also let's assume that the name of these 4 Products are "**Test 1**", "**Test 2**", "**Test 3**", "**Test 4**".
Now if I do a simple search with query "**Test**", in the router "`catalogsearch/index`", then result is showing that there are 4 Products available, which is correct. But if I do a search with query as "**Test 1**", then no results are showing, which is very much weird.

Also I am using "`jQuery`", with no conflict condition. However, there are also 6 plugins of "`jQuery`", all of which are not following the no conflict condition perfectly. This is because the code in some of those plugins are huge, & it is impossible for me to change each & every "`$`" sign to "`jQuery`", making it no conflict compatible. Can anybody suggest for this sort of problem too? And whether it is affecting the Auto Suggest Search in any way?

Comment: Have you tried switching to a default theme temporarily to help determine its your template files or not?  As for the other problem, it sounds like your product indexes need to be rebuilt, you can also try and disable the flat tables to see if it helps.

Comment: @B00mer - I have tried switching to default theme but in vain. There also it's not working. Indexes have been rebuilt many a times, so it's not the fault of product indexes. Lastly, it will be fatal for the project to let go of the use of flat tables, since the client himself demanded that option. :(

Comment: try to wrap your jQuery plugins code with function call and define $ as local scope. Just create a closure and execute it over the plugin code: `function ($) { ..Plugin code goes here.. }(jQuery);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds as though there is an issue with the way that the server is responding to the AJAX calls rather than a problem with the form or the javascript. I would suggest that you need to debug a couple of key areas.

Ideally, you would debug this with Xdebug on your Apache hooked into your IDE (Netbeans, Eclipse, other).  My personal preference/setup is Netbeans, but others will work fine. If you can't use live debugging, you can insert print_r/echo statements through the code blocks and trace the call that way.

1. Mage_CatalogSearch_AjaxController

The javascript on form.mini.phtml should be sending the request to `Mage_CatalogSearch_AjaxController` and the `suggestAction`.  Set breakpoints/trace messages either side of the first `if` statement in this method.

If the breakpoint/trace doesn't get hit, try manually hitting the action by putting `http://hostname/catalogsearch/ajax/suggest?q=query` in your browser address bar.

If that doesn't work, there's something broken with the config of the catalogsearch module, probably to do with the `<frontname><routers>` section.  Use Alan Storm's Configviewer or CommerceBug modules to debug that.

2. Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Autocomplete

The `AjaxController` creates an instance of `Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Autocomplete` which does the actual query. Set a breakpoint/trace just before `$suggestData = $this->getSuggestData();` to check that the Block is getting instantiated.

After that line, the block calls it's own `getSuggestData()` method.  Continue to trace through the code to see where the error occurs.

3. Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Query::getSuggestCollection()

The Block calls this method to retrieve the values that match the `q` param, in particular the `setQueryFilter()` method which inserts the param into the SQL query criteria.  Again, trace through here to find the error.

I can't emphasize enough how much easier you will find this (and most Magento issues) when you're using live debugging in your IDE.  Have a read of [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329248/error-not-all-products-are-available-in-the-requested-quantity-what-does-thi/3348851#3348851) if you want tips on this process.

Make sure that you have the server in [Developer Mode](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/configure_magento_error_page#display_errors_on_the_same_page_developer_mode) to output as many errors as possible.

Comment: First of all, many thanks for such a detailed highlight. But before reading any more of this comment, please read my edited question. Now I have been checking the code, and all it seems is okay, except that I am lost at "`Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Query::getSuggestCollection()`". Also I have worked & manipulated some attributes (some system attributes have been edited to just user-defined ones directly from the database, and have been made out of attribute set), due to client requirements. But how does it affect the auto suggest feature is my major concern. Can you please highlight?

Comment: If you have a separate question re how Search works, please raise a new question and we'll deal with that.  What do you mean you are getting lost at that point, you can't find the file to insert the trace messages?  What is working so far?

Answer (score 4):

Please check one time, that you search after a word, you know, that the product is existing. If it cannot be shown then, press enter and you will be send to result view. After that test, if you can find the article now in suggest search.

Comment: This is a really good point, auto suggest results only come from a cache of prior searches - if you are testing a new store you will only get empty AJAX responses until you actually commit the search, then next time you type that phrase you'll start to get a return value.

Answer (score 3):

If you view the source of a working site (view-source:http://demo.magentocommerce.com/) you should find the search form looks like this:

```
<div class="form-search">
    <label for="search">Search:</label>
    <input id="search" type="text" name="q" value="" class="input-text" />
    <button type="submit" title="Search" class="button"><span><span>Search</span></span></button>
    <div id="search_autocomplete" class="search-autocomplete"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var searchForm = new Varien.searchForm('search_mini_form', 'search', 'Search entire store here...');
        searchForm.initAutocomplete('http://demo.magentocommerce.com/catalogsearch/ajax/suggest/', 'search_autocomplete');
    //]]>
    </script>
</div>
```

The important part seems to be an element called `search_autocomplete` and it's ID is passed to `searchForm.initAutocomplete()`. Also make sure your new theme includes `prototype.js` and the files from `js/varien/` and doesn't have any other Javascript errors.

Comment: All the above has already been done correctly, otherwise the `Firebug` would not have worked fetching the `NULL` / `blank` AJAX responses. :( Question edited, as per your answer.

Comment: can you post the URL that Firebug shows that the AJAX request is being submitted to?

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem ... it looks like there is a bug in the search or a conflict with some extension mabye the German Markets one ....

Check what you get if you enter this: http://www.studio-ausruestung.de/catalogsearch/ajax/suggest/?q=% with your sitename of course.

Normaly you have to get all results ...

Comment: blank page as ajax response, help please.