# Magento redirects to homepage after item removed from cart

Tags: php, magento, checkout

## Question

We're using Magento ver. 1.7.0.1 and we have an issue where a user removes an item from the cart and the cart will redirect back to the homepage instead of conventionally just returning to the checkout page (even with zero items).

### Background

We have the site setup in a sub-folder on a staging server and it works - perfectly.

What could possibly be different between the two that this would happen? The servers themselves are very similar. Ubuntu 10.04, PHP 5.3+, etc

I can only think of it maybe being a pathing issue (but no luck in tracking that down)

I did try what was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223960/when-removing-an-item-from-the-cart-magento-redirects-to-store-home-page-instea) as a "quickfix", but alas, no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's only happening on your live and not staging server, it seems unlikely that it's a code related problem. Try performing the action in FireFox with the extension TamperData Installed and enabled. As you step through the steps you should get a good indication of where the site is trying to send you, with a bit of luck you'll see an extra redirect in there and it'll immediately click what's going on. Short of that make sure logging is enabled (System > Configuration > Developer > Log Settings) and check that there are no actual errors occurring.

The deleteAction calls _redirectReferer, passing in `*/*` (which should in-turn become `checkout/cart`). The _redirectReferer function follows 3 paths.

1. If there is a referrer url, then redirect to it.
2. If no referrer url, but there is a default url, redirect to that
3. Otherwise redirect to the homepage.

Based on those facts you might immediately assume that step 3 is happening, but since the deleteAction is passing an argument it should be impossible to get passed step 2, since there will always be a default url.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by following steps.

Navigate to `"app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\CartController.php".`

Find "`deleteAction()`" function and the function will look like bellow.

> public function deleteAction()
>       {
>
> ```
>     $id = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
>     if ($id) {
>         try {
>             $this->_getCart()->removeItem($id)
>               ->save();
>         } catch (Exception $e) {
>             $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Cannot remove the item.'));
>             Mage::logException($e);
>         }
>     }
>     $this->_redirectReferer(Mage::getUrl('*/*'));
> }
> ```

You need to change the line `"$this->_redirectReferer(Mage::getUrl('*/*'));"` to `$this->_redirect('checkout/cart');`. So now the function will look like below.

```
public function deleteAction()
    {
        $id = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        if ($id) {
            try {
                $this->_getCart()->removeItem($id)
                  ->save();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Cannot remove the item.'));
                Mage::logException($e);
            }
        }
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
    }
```

The above is not a proffered way to do that. I just explained the place to debug. Try to [create a module](http://inchoo.net/dev-talk/how-to-extend-magento-core-controller/) and override the above function. That's the proffered way.

For more information refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8499720/3049065).

Thanks