# My proceed to checkout button is missing, what steps can I take to diagnose?

Tags: php, magento, checkout

When I am in the shopping cart "proceed to checkout" button is missing and I can't go any further in the checkout process. I looked at cart.phtml and $methodHtml is empty so the comparison (`if ($methodHtml = $this->getMethodHtml($method))`)to find checkout methods never shows the button.

I am wondering if anyone might know how I can track down what might be wrong with Magento. Onestepcheckout is installed but even when disabled it makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn how to debug through the code using an IDE.  Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329248/error-not-all-products-are-available-in-the-requested-quantity-what-does-thi/3348851#3348851).

Once you have the debugging setup working for you, set breakpoints in `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Link` in the `isDisabled()` and `isPossibleOnepageCheckout()` methods so that you can trace through what is causing the button to be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Need more information, but you if this is an overriden module then I think I can help.

I had this recently,  you need to make to make sure the form controls are rewritten in the new module as well.

For instance, in config.xml....

```
    <blocks>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite><!-- required to add the form controls -->
        <checkout_onepage>CHRIS_Checkout_Block_Onepage</checkout_onepage>
            </rewrite>


        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
```

Set up debugging is a pain but a pleasure when you start to see what is being called and from where.